# Constructor parameters not being deployed on the blockchain issue #1118

Tags: solidity, web3js

this issue has been closed however I still see this in my code, contract deplyes, but the constructor does not see the args, I have tried this with both, version 1.0.0-beta-30 as well as 1.0.0-beta-36

here is my code, would appreciate any help...abi and bytecode are too long to paste here, but I can provide those if needed

`

```
let bContract =  new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
let hexdata = bContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode,
    arguments: ["testbet", ["one", "two", "three" ], 123, 200],
});


let rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(9),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
    data: "0x" + hexdata,
    from: runENV.acctAddr,
}

let tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(runENV.privateKeyBuffer);

let serialzedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serialzedTx.toString("hex"))
    .on('receipt', console.log);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
let hexdata = bContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode,
    arguments: ["testbet", ["one", "two", "three" ], 123, 200],
}).encodeABI();  // <-- note this
```

and then just:

```
let rawTx = {
    ...
    data: hexdata,
```

Comment: worked..mucho gracias...